# Perfect rotation of a cube

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a script to move my "Player" around a surface but I find it very uneffective, the cube wiggles left to right and up and down. Does anyone have any good scrips on how to move a cube, flipping side to side, without wiggling or whatever. that also moves perfectly each time? my last one would move to a point like 2.000231 or something like that. it was really fusterating because I'm trying to have it perfect so it would fit in an hole. He's the script I am using. If you have a better one pls include ty
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

```
public class TumblingCubes : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float tumblingDuration = 0.2f;

    void Update()
    {
        var dir = Vector3.zero;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            dir = Vector3.forward;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            dir = Vector3.back;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            dir = Vector3.left;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            dir = Vector3.right;

        if (dir != Vector3.zero && !isTumbling)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Tumble(dir));
        }

    }

    bool isTumbling = false;
    IEnumerator Tumble(Vector3 direction)
    {
        isTumbling = true;

        var rotAxis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, direction);
        var pivot = (transform.position + Vector3.down * 0.5f) + direction * 0.5f;

        var startRotation = transform.rotation;
        var endRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90.0f, rotAxis) * startRotation;

        var startPosition = transform.position;
        var endPosition = transform.position + direction;

        var rotSpeed = 90.0f / tumblingDuration;
        var t = 0.0f;

        while (t < tumblingDuration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            transform.RotateAround(pivot, rotAxis, rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.rotation = endRotation;
        transform.position = endPosition;

        isTumbling = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please stop reposting this, you only need to post it once.

Answer (score 1):

Your script should work just fine, you will always have small errors because of how float numbers are stored. But you shouldn't have errors as big as yours.

Are sure your cube is starting from (0,0,0)?
Anyway you can be sure if you put this in the end of the Tumble

```
    var vec = transform.eulerAngles;
    vec.x = Mathf.RoundToInt(vec.x / 90 * 90);
    vec.y = Mathf.RoundToInt(vec.y / 90 * 90);
    vec.z = Mathf.RoundToInt(vec.z / 90 * 90);
    transform.eulerAngles = vec;
```

Comment: im so puzzled, piror to running the program, the cube is at 0,0,0 once i start it, it literally doesnt show movement but it says its moving all over, coordinates constally moving but the cube actually isnt moving...?

Comment: and should I put your codde here? : 
        while (t < tumblingDuration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            transform.RotateAround(pivot, rotAxis, rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.rotation = endRotation;
        transform.position = endPosition;

        

        isTumbling = false;


        vec.x = Mathf.RoundToInt(vec.x / 90 * 90);
        vec.y = Mathf.RoundToInt(vec.y / 90 * 90);
        vec.z = Mathf.RoundToInt(vec.z / 90 * 90);
    }

    
}

Comment: Are you sure you don't have rigidbody attached to the cube?